# Is there any way to add new labels to an already initialized metric?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prometheus, metrics, prom-client

I'm using prom-client npm package to monitor my app. I've read [here](https://github.com/siimon/prom-client#labels) that "All metrics can take a labelNames property in the configuration object. All label names that the metric support needs to be declared here. (in the object given to the constructor)". I've to design a programmable interface that lets you define what labels do you want see in your time series.
For example you want `sameMetric{label1=value1}` and `sameMetric{label2=value2}`. Same metric but the time series have different labels

The only possible solution I can think of is that i must predeclare every single possible label name, but that's not the best solution because there's a plenty of them (session properties).

So if you know a better solution, let me know. Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I haven't tried anything, because as the documentum claims you must predeclare every label. I'm just curious if there's any possible way to add new labels. In my opinion declaring like 30 possible label name is not the best solution, but it works. AND it's also not the best, because i have to hardcode every single label name. (in my case: session object has like 20 properties, and the user should choose between them). It's my first question here, so kinda hard to express myself on the topic, if u have anything else let me know.

Comment: In this instance declaring all label names manually is actually a very normal way to do things. If you look at some popular packages like node-exporter, that's the way things are done. You really shouldn't be changing the label names very often anyway since it's going to be a breaking change for any consumers of the data. If you're just opposed to typing things manually I suggest generating the code instead.

Comment: @JacobColvin Alright thank you, this was the answer i was waiting for, to make sure that it's the only way of doing it, but mainly it's the correct way.